# define-macro namespace in Gambit-C Scheme

Tags: scheme, gambit

Four modules:

1. Defines library functions
2. Defines library macros that use library functions
3. Defines application functions that use library macros
4. Loads the other three

libfunc.scm:

```
(define (my-func ls) ...)
```

libmacro.scm:

```
(define-macro (my-macro ls) (define mfls (my-func ls)) `...
```

libapp.scm

```
(define app (begin (my-macro '(1 2 3 ...
```

libmain.scm

```
(load "libfunc.scm")
(load "libmacro.scm")
(load "libapp.scm")
(define (main . args) (app ...
```

Porting from another scheme where this works to Gambit-C where it doesn't. I'm starting to think it's impossible. Gambit-C has `##define-macro` and `##namespace` which might be relevant but are documented nowhere and un-googlable. One thing I did find in Meroon, which is a big library portable across many Schemes, is this code for working around Gambit-C.

**Edit**: I think Christian Queinnec, Meroon's author, had a good handle on the issues. He wrote [23 things I know about modules for Scheme](http://www.eighty-twenty.org/repos/macromod/doc/reference/sws.pdf). I feel like if I spoke both French and Scheme that it would give me all the answers.

**Edit 2**: I took a look at the original Scheme which was pretty-much purpose built to run the system I'm trying to port. It turns out they cheat. Every "function" that is called from a `define-macro` has a shadow-implementation in C that is attached to the macro-global namespace. That might be a trick I can copy in Gambit-C since it is very C oriented but I'm still researching that possibility.

I don't know if it's possible to call normally `define`d functions from a macro using syntax case. I can't find anything easy-to-understand about it (most documentation seems to be written by and for phds) but there's a very interesting tutorial on `define-syntax` and `syntax-case` which shows that you can implement any function as a macro. It even implements a basic Lisp in macros. So that's something. [JRM's Syntax-rules Primer for the Merely Eccentric](http://hipster.home.xs4all.nl/lib/scheme/gauche/define-syntax-primer.txt)

**Edit 3**: Like @GoZoner says this can be done using `for-syntax` and `define-syntax`, at least in Racket. Remains to be seen if it can work in Gambit-C

```
#lang racket

(require srfi/1)
(require (for-syntax srfi/1))
(require (for-syntax syntax/stx))

(define-syntax (fnodup x)
  (define mydat (delete-duplicates (syntax->datum x)))

  (syntax-case mydat ()
    [(fnodup f) #'(f) ]
    [(fnodup f x0) #'(f x0) ]
    [(fnodup f x0 ...) #'(f '(x0 ...)) ]
     ))

(fnodup print "hi" "der" "hi")
```

`(require (for-syntax ...` is where the magic happens. Racket has it. Gambit-C doesn't.

Comment: Your `(define-syntax (fnodup x) ...)` isn't Scheme either; but often Racket is not Scheme too.  What is it you are trying to macrofy?

Answer (score 2):

When 'new to Scheme', stick to Scheme.  The syntactic form 'define-macro' is not part of any Scheme standard and is, from the example you've given, a highly inferior macro system compared to what is in the Scheme standard.

Look at R5RS, R6RS or R7RS to understand `syntax-rules` as your step #1.  After that `syntax-case` in R6RS lets you do other stuff.

Comment: Believe me I'm no fan of `define-macro` but the original author used it pervasively in his spaghetti code. My hope is to get it working without a big rewrite.

Comment: @MichaelFox Alas, a rewrite may be inevitable. I'll see if I can rewrite what you've posted into `syntax-case`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I would be elated to see any example of calling a normally `define`'d function from a macro that works in Gambit.